# Typescript "Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '(() => any)"

Tags: typescript

I have a Vue component with Typescript and I keep receiving the error stated in the title of this issue, even though I declared types. The (simplified) component looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const Component = Vue.extend({
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    },
    index: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    stepNumber(): number {
      return this.index + 1;
    }
  }
})

export default Component;
```

The issue is being raised for "this.index+1". To me this doesn't make sense, because I declared type 'number' for prop 'index'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your `index` has no type `number`, it has object type with properties named `type`, and `default`.
Also `Number` is JS built-in [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object, not type `number`.

More about types in TS:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already had the feeling that 'Number' != 'number'. I'm new to Vue, do you have a suggestion on how to fix this and declare the types of props differently (preferably without decorators).

Comment: Unfortunatelly I dont know Vue, and I dont know what You intented to do. You must wait for another response, or go to the Vue documentation.

Comment: Alright, then I'll leave this question open for a little longer and check the documentation more thoroughly. Thanks anways.